# How to make a chart series change colour based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a chart series(point) change colour depending on a specific value in a cell. However I keep getting a object required error.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Column = 12 And (Target.Row >= 2 And Target.Row <= 37) Then
  If Target.Value = "Stage Gate 5" Then Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
  Else
  MsgBox ("error")
  End If
 End If
 End Sub
```

The idea is that I've got a bar graph with projects on it with start and finish dates and they go through stage gates I need each bar change colour depending on the stage gate.

Any help anyone can give would be great appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to run on a `Worksheet_Change` event? If so, place it the code inside an actual `Worksheet_Change` procedure in a `Worksheet` module. As written the `Object Required` error happens because `Target` is undefined in the code.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to VBA. I don't really know what a worksheet_change event is. I'm just trying to make it so that when a cell changes from "Stage gate 5" "Stage Gate 4", "Stage Gate 1" that the graph series changes colour.

Comment: [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) a good place to start reading Adam. You'll need a `Worksheet_Change` event to accomplish this, since a regular procedure needs a button or another trigger to run. A worksheet_change event will trigger each time a cell changes. There's also more available online should you need more help with this. Or come back here as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott I've managed to get the code to work now!!!! However it only it only appears to work if the code is typed in. currently the column that has the different stage gates in is a vlook up that looks at if statement formula and if the conditions of the formula changes this doesn't work. Nothing happens. I did try and create a macro button that copies the values from one column to another and changed the code above to the next column but that give me a type mismatch error that points at the If Target.Value ="Stage Gate 5" Then line.

Comment: Try `Worksheet_Calculate` event.

Comment: I have done but this gives me a compiler error

Comment: Are you changing multiple ranges at once?

Comment: this is my current code `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then
      If Target.Value = "Stage Gate 5" Then
    Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
      Else
       MsgBox "error"
       End If
      End If
    End Sub` sorry if this is not very readable

Comment: The argument list for `Worksheet_Change` is empty. Remove `ByVal Target As Range`.

Comment: sorry Scott i'm getting myself confused the i have the give the compiler error is `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then
 If Target.Value = "Stage Gate 5" Then
 Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
 Else
  MsgBox "error"
  End If
 End If
End Sub` it give a compiler error like this and with out the `ByVal Target As Range` it gives and object required error

Comment: see my answer Adam. Target will not work with `Worksheet_Calculate` since its undefined. You can use another variable set on your own or just the range directly.

Comment: You could do it without any VBA.  http://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Range("M2") = "Stage Gate 5" Then 
    Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).‌​Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
Else
    Msgbox "error"
End If

End Sub
```